# Extracting data from a RethinkDB Count object

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I have a **JavaScript** RethinkDB query that looks like this:

```
r.db('test')
  .table('trolleys')
  .eqJoin(r.row('currect_location')('_id'),r.table('bufferzone'))
  .zip()
  .filter(r.row('currect_destination')('_id').ne('DEPOT'))
  .group('id')
  .count()
```

The query produces the following output which is exactly what I am looking for

```
[
  {
    "group":  "a" ,
    "reduction": 2
  },
  {
    "group":  "b" ,
    "reduction": 1
  }
]
```

However, when performing the same query in **Java**:

```
Count countObj = r.db("test")
    .table("trolleys")
    .eqJoin(row -> row.g("currect_location").g("_id"), r.table("bufferzone"))
    .zip()
    .filter(row -> row.g("currect_destination").g("_id").ne("DEPOT"))
    .group("id")
    .count();
```

I get a `Count` object back as the response, but how do I extract data similar to what I got in the JavaScript case from this `Count` object in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The solution was to call the `run()` method in the end of the query. The type returned from the query was in fact also wrong in the posted question. Instead of a `Count` object the query returns a list of `GroupedResults`, i.e. a `List<GroupedResult>`. For completeness the full solution is given here:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.model.GroupedResult;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

public class EmptyTrolleysInBufferzone {

    public static final RethinkDB r = RethinkDB.r;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = r.connection().hostname("localhost").port(28015).connect();

        List<GroupedResult> response = r.db("test")
            .table("trolleys")
            .eqJoin(row -> row.g("currect_location").g("_id"), r.table("bufferzone"))
            .zip().filter(row -> row.g("currect_destination").g("_id").ne("DEPOT"))
            .group("id")
            .count()
            .run(conn);

        for (GroupedResult g : response) {
            System.out.println(g.group + " = " + g.values.toString());
        }

        conn.close();
    }
}
```